# task not serializable error while performing an RDD map function scala

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

trust me on this one, I have tried really hard toiling night and day but just just could not get hold of this Task not serializable error which is now totally eating me out!.

And I understand there are many similar questions floating around on SO but either am I really too dumb to get those (I am not expecting any spoon feeding in here) or mine being a different bug story altogether.

Totally requesting you guys to have a look at this one :

```
class RootServer(val config: Config) extends Configurable with Server with Serializable {
      var PKsAffectedDF: DataFrame = dataSource.getAffectedPKs(prevBookMark,currBookMark)
      if(PKsAffectedDF.rdd.isEmpty()){
              Holder.log.info("[SQL] no records to upsert in the internal Status Table == for bookmarks : "+prevBookMark+" ==and== "+currBookMark+" for table == "+dataSource.db+"_"+dataSource.table)
      }
      val PKsAffectedDF_json = PKsAffectedDF.toJSON
      PKsAffectedDF_json.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords => {
        var props = new Properties()
        props.put('','')
        props.put('','')
        props.put('','')
        props.put('','')
        val producer = new KafkaProducer[String,String](props)
                partitionOfRecords.foreach
                {
                    case x:String=>{
                        println(x)

                        val message=new ProducerRecord[String, String]("[TOPIC] "+dbname+"_"+dbtable,dbname,x)
                        producer.send(message)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Now Config is the typesafe.config Class which I believe is serializable, and server class is a basic abstract class with just two methods. I am totally stuck at what would be giving the following stacktrace :

http://pastebin.com/5yPA1s7e Sorry for pastebinning it but the entire stacktrace is there.

Thanks in Advance peeps.

Comment: Hi Sumit, Any Luck ??

Comment: Yes! sorry I dint update, basically, so in your map / foreach function (being applied to each row, basically), you must must must must never pass any object that instantiates a non serializable class! that is it! in my case i in order to remove a few hardcodings was using some yaml parser type thing which was not serializable! that's it. I hardcoded the servers groups etc etc and other config params and it worked!

Comment: Thank you . :) Solved it too